Challenges in Previewing Uploaded Excel Files in Angular Application
I have a development challenge where I need to preview an uploaded Excel file in an Angular project. The workflow involves uploading an Excel/PDF file, which is then stored in the database as a byte[] with a BLOB column type. In the next step, we need to retrieve the specific byte[] and send it to the frontend to preview the uploaded file.
For PDF files, it works perfectly with the following code:
previewPdfFile(byteArray: Uint8Array) {
const blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/pdf' });
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    this.pdfUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
}

<iframe *ngIf="pdfUrl" [src]="pdfUrl" width="100%" height="600px"></iframe>

I tried the same approach for Excel by changing the type, but it didn’t work as expected. Instead of previewing the Excel file, it’s getting downloaded.
previewExcelFile(byteArray: Uint8Array) {
    const blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    this.excelUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
}

<iframe *ngIf="excelUrl" [src]="excelUrl" width="100%" height="600px"></iframe>

I also tried installing the "xlsx" library and it ended up reading the Excel content and displaying all the cell values as labels, it works but isn’t an ideal solution for previewing the file.
previewExcelFile(byteArray: Uint8Array) {
const workbook = XLSX.read(byteArray, { type: 'array' });

const sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];

    this.data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, { header: 1 });
}

<table *ngIf="data.length">
  <tr *ngFor="let row of data">
    <td *ngFor="let cell of row">{{ cell }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

Does anyone have a better approach for previewing an Excel file without downloading it or printing cell values as labels?

the only reason the PDF version of the code works is that some browsers have a built-in PDF viewer.  There is no such built-in viewer for Excel files.
